# jUnit tests with Jersey test framework run individually but not together

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jersey-test-framework

I'm running jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory and jersey-test-framework-core both version 2.26.

The issue I have is I'm able to run each test on their own and they run as expected. However, whenever I run the three tests together two of them always return a 404 when I'm expecting a 200.

The API that is being tested calls an external XML API and transforms the data to JSON which is returned to the client.

I can't for the life of me workout why these tests are falling over as a group.

My Code is:

```
 @Override
public Application configure() {
    return super.configure(EnquiryResource.class);
}

 @Before
public void retrieveJWTToken() throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = Resources.getResource("jwt.token").openStream();
    this.TOKEN = IOUtils.toString(stream);
    stream.close();
}

@Test
public void testOne() {
    Response output = target("/").path(URL)
            .queryParam(OPTION1, YesNoType.YES)
            .queryParam(OPTION2, YesNoType.YES)
            .queryParam(OPTION3, YesNoType.YES)
            .queryParam(OPTION4, 36)
            .request().get();

    assertEquals("Should return 200", 200, output.getStatus());
}

 @Test
public void TestTwo() {
    Response output = target("/").path(URL).path(PARAM)
            .queryParam(OPTION1, YesNoType.YES)
            .queryParam(OPTION2, YesNoType.YES)
            .queryParam(OPTION3, YesNoType.YES)
            .request().get();

    assertEquals("Should return 204", 204, output.getStatus());
}

 @Test
public void TestThree() {
    Response output = target("/").path(INCORRECT_URL).path(PARAM)
           .queryParam(OPTION1, YesNoType.YES)
            .queryParam(OPTION2, YesNoType.YES)
            .queryParam(OPTION3, YesNoType.YES)
            .request().get();

    assertEquals("Should return 404", 404, output.getStatus());
}
```

Any advice or recommendations will be appreciated.

Comment: You talk about 3 tests, I only see one in the code. So it's difficult to compare them and help you. Just a wild guess: do you run a reset/setup before every test. It could be that the other tests influence the next once.

Comment: @RonNabuurs Updated for you. The strange thing is when i run two at a time they pass but if i add a third they fail. No I don't have a reset/setup before every test. I'll give that a try to see if it solves the issue.

Comment: `TestThree` is exactly the same as `TestTwo` except for the `assertEquals`. So that should fail indeed because they request exaclty the same yet you want an other `assertEquals`

Comment: Sorry I typed that wrong test Three has a different path I've updated the post to reflect this

Comment: Do you change something in the database or something with Test Two? Maybe thats why test three fails? Or maybe becaus you only use configure once and don't reset it everytime?

Comment: No, all I'm doing is calling the external service and checking the status. Nothing that complicated.

Comment: I found the issue it was a static in the YesNoType. Thanks for the support

Comment: Alright no problem, glad I could help even though I did nothing